# Export MYSQL to .csv from two tables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I got 2 tables **Tickets** and **Replies**.

**Tickets got this fields:** id, dname, mname, subject, priority, message, date, last_reply, status, close_mname, cdfileds

**Replies got this fileds:** id, tid, mname, message, date

The tables are a support tickets.
I want to export tables to CSV.
This is the code I use.

```
<?php
/* vars for export */
// database record to be exported
$db_record = 'trxp_tickets';
$db_record2 = 'trxp_replies'; // added by me
// optional where query
$where = 'WHERE 1 ORDER BY 1';
// filename for export
$csv_filename = 'db_export_'.$db_record.'_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv';
// database variables
$hostname = "localhost";
$user = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$database = "xxxxxx";
// Database connecten voor alle services
mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $password)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database)
    or die ('Could not select database ' . mysql_error());
// create empty variable to be filled with export data
$csv_export = '';
// query to get data from database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,dname,mname,subject,priority,message,date,last_reply,status,close_mname,cdfields FROM ".$db_record." ".$where);
$field = mysql_num_fields($query);
// create line with field names
for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
    $csv_export.= mysql_field_name($query,$i).';';
}
// newline (seems to work both on Linux & Windows servers)
$csv_export.= '
';
// loop through database query and fill export variable
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    // create line with field values
    for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
        $csv_export.= '"'.$row[mysql_field_name($query,$i)].'";';
    }   
    $csv_export.= '
';  
}
// Export the data and prompt a csv file for download
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
echo($csv_export);
?>
```

In the code, it is not included in the second table when I make the SELEC, For doubles results. Try using UNION and UNION ALL but did not work.
I would like to stay in the CSV listed below each ticket responses.

Comment: Ok, but how you want to export data? Two files? One file with all columns from both tables? Another option?

Comment: One file. I wish i could have Ticket #1 and in the next line/s the replies to ticket #1. Then Ticket #2 and replies from ticket #2 and so on. But the fileds are different, so I don't know if that can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your SQL to get data from both tables:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT 
                          r1.id, r1.dname, r1.mname, r1.subject,
                          r1.priority, r1.message,
                          DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(r1.date), '%d/%m/%Y') as r1_date,
                          r1.last_reply, r1.status, r1.close_mname,
                          r1.cdfields,
                          r2.id, r2.tid, r2.mname,
                          r2.message
                          DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(r2.date), '%d/%m/%Y') as r2_date,
                     FROM ".$db_record." r1
               INNER JOIN ".$db_record2." r2 
                       ON r1.id = r2.tid
                          ".$where.");
```

This should do the trick.

mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should change to mysqli_* or PDO. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Thanks. The code works, but with one problem, it duplicate results in the CVS file. Maybe it more easy to show in the first columns the Tickets Fileds and continue the Replies filelds. `Example: id, dname, mname, subject, .... id, tid, mname,....` In one line the tickets fileds and the replies.

Comment: Alter your select to get only the data you need. `SELECT r1.id, ...  FROM ...`

Comment: Still duplicate,. i don't know why, but every ticket is duplicate 8 times, that is the total of tickets. Another issue is it possible to change the format of the date when you make the selection? I have this date format: 1459195461 and I want dd / mm / yyyy. Thanks Felippe.

Comment: You probably have 8 replies for this ticket. And yes, you can transform your data format.

Comment: First ¿how do I transform the data format, for dates? I've seach, but all I tried give me error. And second, is the same reply duplicated 8 times. I'm doing tests, so I generate all the tickets and replies.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got this error now **Warning: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home5/wrgrbrvh/public_html/soporte/admin/manage/export_csv.php on line 37** and the line 37 is `$field = mysql_num_fields($query);`. I made some changes to try to solve, but with no luck.

Comment: You probably made a mistake with your new SQL. Try to run directly into your database, see what errors you get and fix it.